# Use guest vm vpn from host

Tags: windows, networking, macos, vpn, parallels

I have a vpn connexion inside a vm and I want to use it from the host.
The host is a MacOS Ventura M2 and the guest is a windows 11, Im using parallels.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It depends upon the VPN:  SSH maybe; IPSec probably not.